# PHP code write in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

can any one tell me that how can i write these PHP codes in Smarty .

```
<?php (($user_info.bank != "") ? echo "readonly" : "") ?>
```

this is a if statement is there any thing i am typing writing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but a standard if statement in smarty looks like this.

```
{if $user_info.bank != ""}readonly{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, export 'bank' to the smarty template.

`$smarty->assign('bank', $user_info.bank);`

Then, write

`{if $bank neq ''}readonly{/if}`